# How to change default camera app

Tags: 8.0, camera

Is there an option to change a default camera app so when I press the button it would open other program than default? I'm using **Camera360** app, if it matters.

Comment: Any of those answers responds what your wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Now a days is not possible for every app show as an option to be the default camera app.

To change the default camera app you need to go to *Settings*, *applications*, *photos+camera* and select the camera app of your choice in "*Pressing the camera button opens*".

I have the app you had mention and it is not listed as an option.

[image]

I suppose this can be a restricted permission allowed only to OEM but can't confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the Settings app, scroll across to the applications tab, you should find a "photos+camera" section - in this, there is an option to choose the camera application to launch when pressing the camera button.